# How to get Type when i using navigation in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

I have a Frame is defined in MainPage:

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed"  Navigating="ContentFrame_Navigating">
                <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Function/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/Function/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
                </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame>
```

and in code behind:

```
string uriStr = "/Function/Page1";
//check it here
if(uriStr is available) //available mean can navigate to uriStr
{
    ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri(uriStr,UriKind.Relative));
}
```

1./ How can i check "uriStr" is available before call method .Navigate()?

2./ How can i get Type of page if "uriStr" is available?

Please, help me!!!
Thank!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

> How can i check "uriStr" is available before call method .Navigate()?

I don't know the answer, but I am sure there is some way through reflection. What I do is handle the `ContentFrame_NavigationFailed` event which depending on why you want to know if it exists, should work for you.

For the second question:

> How can i get Type of page if "uriStr" is available?

Not sure where in your code your trying to get this but what I do is grab the page in the `ContentFrame_Navigated` event using this code:

```
If TypeOf e.Content Is Page Then
    _CurrentPage = e.Content
Else
    _CurrentPage = Nothing
End If
```

And then I can use it where ever I like. If you want this in the `ContentFrame_Navigating` event, you'll have to look into reflection but I don't think it will help much because you won't have the instance of the page that has not been created yet since this event is before that happens.

Comment: Thanks Steve.

I want to use reflection to check them before a instance is active.
But i don't know how do this. I only have a string to start my work.